# SPICE and Maxwell capacitance matrix

Tags: circuit-analysis, simulation, layout, parasitic-capacitance

From this link I understand the definitions of a Maxwell matrix and a SPICE matrix

[Maxwell and Spice Matrices - ANSYS](https://courses.ansys.com/index.php/courses/ansys-q3d-signal-integrity-getting-started/lessons/capacitance-matrix-reduction-lesson-4/)

However, what is the meaning of a negative main-diagonal entry in a SPICE matrix? Since the main diagonal element in this matrix is the self-capacitance or the capacitance between this point and ground on a PCB. For example, I have this matrix from a parasitic extraction simulation I ran,

**EDIT 1:**

Here is the maxwell matrix which confirms the values of the cap to Ground value,
[image]

[image]

Comment: What does your Maxwell matrix look like?

Comment: @SteKulov edited the answer, thanks!

Comment: I don't know enough regarding the tools/software you're using, but it sounds like the physical phenomena you're modeling for simulation is best done using things not physically realizable such as a negative capacitor.  On the other hand, a SPICE simulator has no problem using the negative values in its internal calculations.  The only thing that changes is the phase response, since a negative C changes \$\frac{1}{j \omega C}\$ to \$\frac{j}{\omega C}\$.